# Determine the error term of SKEW-calculation

Tags: programming, volatility-skew, math

I am trying to recreate the CBOE's [SKEW](https://www.cboe.com/micro/skew/documents/skewwhitepaperjan2011.pdf) Index in Python. I need to calculate the errors terms that are adjustment terms for the differences between the `atm strike` and the `forward`.

[image]

My formula's

```
error_term_1 = -1 * (1 + np.log(forward / atm_strike) - (forward / atm_strike))
error_term_2 = 2 * np.log(atm_strike / forward) * ((forward / atm_strike) - 1) + ((np.log(atm_strike / forward) ** 2) / 2)
error_term_3 = 3 * (np.log(atm_strike / forward) ** 2) * ((np.log(atm_strike / forward) / 3) - 1 + (forward / atm_strike))
```

According to the example when the `forward` is equal to `1106.85` and the `atm_strik`e is equal to `1105`, the correct values are:

```
epilson_1 = 1.40E-06
epilson_2 = -4.2E-0.6
epilson_3 = 1.176E-11
```

My first and second formula gives the correct answer. My third formula doesn't however. What do I need to change?

I see in different [source](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/6d/2f/91/ba3d3c4eb8bbac/US20120221482A1.pdf) that the definition is as follows:

[image]

Still I am getting a different result when I remove `3`.. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the third equation they somehow did not put the 1/3 in front of the second ln-term.

Without the 1/3, the equation looks at follows:

```
error_term_3 = 3 * (np.log(atm_strike / forward) ** 2) * (np.log(atm_strike / forward) - 1 + (forward / atm_strike))
```

Filling in `F0 = 1106.85` and `K0 = 1105` gives `Epsilon3 = 1.1752170209137409e-11`, which is the answer you are looking for.